# Como verificar se o código do produto que eu estou cadastrando já está presente nos produtos do array em python?

Tags: python, classes, atributos

Olá!
Estou fazendo um exercício onde tenho uma classe produtos:

```
class Produtos():
    codigo = 0
    nome = ''
    preco = 0.0
```

eu devo criar os produtos e adicioná-los em um array, mas antes de dar o append, preciso verificar se o código introduzido já existe em algum produto do vetor.

tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
    p=Produtos()
    codigo = int(input("Código: "))
    while any(codigo in p.codigo for p in vet_produtos):
            codigo = int(input("Código já existente! Informe outro código: "))
    p.codigo = codigo
    p.nome = str(input("Nome: "))
    p.preco = float(input("Preço: "))
    vet_produtos.append(p)
```

mas esta verificação, no segundo produto a ser adicionado, acaba saindo da função e me jogando direto na main.

Que tipo de verificação posso fazer pra saber se existe, dentro de um vetor, um objeto cuja propriedade específica seja igual ao valor que eu defini?

Comment: Essa não é abordagem mais eficiente para se fazer isso, talvez o uso de um dicionário com as chaves indexando os produtos fosse mais eficiente. Mas em todo o caso aqui `while any(codigo in p.codigo for p in vet_produtos):` não seria `while any(codigo == p.codigo for p in vet_produtos):`

Comment: colaborando para entender, o operador `in` é  bem usual para  objetos iteráveis seja  `listas` ou `tuplas` e a forma indicada `while any(codigo == p.codigo...`  faz sentido pois  o  `in`verifica se o valor está contido na lista **MAS**  O operador `"=="` compara os  dois valores  verificando se são iguais que no caso do código faz toda a diferença.

Answer (score -4):

Acredito que o problema está na condição do seu >while<. Ao utilizar any(codigo in p.codigo for p in vet_produtos), você está verificando se o valor de codigo está contido na lista de dígitos de seu código que compõem p.codigo, e não se codigo é igual a p.codigo. (não sei se vai conseguir entender kkk)

Tem Uma forma de verificar se o código já existe em algum produto do vetor o jeito é utilizando um loop for para percorrer todos os produtos já cadastrados e comparar o código de cada um deles com o código informado pelo usuário<
Vou dar um exemplo:

[Exemplo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqIe6.png)

Neste exemplo que dei, a variável codigo_existente é utilizada para marcar se o código informado já existe ou não no vetor. Se o código já existir, o loop continua pedindo ao usuário um novo código. Se não existir, o loop é interrompido e o novo produto é adicionado ao vetor. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Emerson, muito obrigado. Não sei por que estão dando avaliações negativas para o seu código. Talvez existam formas mais eficientes, mas o que você me mostrou é exatamente o que eu tava tentando pensar ontem e não consegui sozinho. Estou no primeiro ano de Analise de Sistemas, e essa gambiarra já resolve meu problema completamente. Bigadão mesmo!